# Animation 2d don't play

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have a jump animation inAir and landing animation but if start the game and remove my jump delay variable the character won't jump and animation sometimes starts with in when charater variable in inAir but Jump animation don't start. How can i fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6f40.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jYxP.png)

```
        // Jump here
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && _jumpTimeoutDelta <= 0.0f)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            if (_hasAnimator)
            {
                anim.SetBool(_animIDJump, true);
                Debug.Log("inJump");
            }
        }
```

Comment: If i have cooldown on jupm in 0.2m/s this error does not appear

Comment: Is `HasExitTime` enabled on your transitions?